# Change the cell value depends upon the values in the 8 neighborhood cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My excel sheet contains 400 data points,its like a image pixel values,but some of my data points are missing so the value of that cell is zero,the data consist only four values 1,2,3 and 4. I need to assign a value to missing cells by looking the neighborhood 8 cells and if any value have more number of counts then it will assigned as the value of missing cell

Comment: Please share with us what have you tried so far? What is the rule for the calculation, average of the neighbours? Do you want to achieve it with a macro (please add VBA tag for your question), or with standard formulas (please add tag worksheet-function)?

Comment: My data consist of only 4 values. assign any one of these values in the missing cell by which value have more number of counts in the neighborhood of vacant cell. I prefer formulas

Comment: Missing data points are not blank it had a value=0

Comment: what are the four values do you have? if two have the same count than are you happy just with one of them? Please don't answer in comment but edit your question, also please edit into your question your previous answer.

Comment: It is going to be a long and crappy formula.  If the spreadsheet is that simple, then exporting it to a csv and a small script would be far quicker.

Comment: What do you want in the case where the two most frequent surrounding numbers have equal counts? Can a hole be along the edge?  If so, what sourounding cells are used?  Which version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. duplicate your entire worksheet
2. enter this formula in the upper left corner of the new range: `=IF(Sheet1!B2>0,Sheet1!B2,IFERROR(INDEX(MODE.MULT(Sheet1!A1:C3),1),MAX(Sheet1!A1:C3)))`
3. Copy the formula through the whole range

The formula:

- `=IF(Sheet1!B2>0,...)` - if the original value was >0, then doesn't change it
- `INDEX(MODE.MULT(Sheet1!A1:C3),1)` - `MODE.MULT` returns all modes of the selected range, `INDEX` just selects the first one. (`MODE.MULT` results an array of results, it's available only from Excel 2010. As the formula uses only its first item it's not necessary to enter the formulas as an array formula)
- `IFERROR(...,MAX(Sheet1!A1:C3))` - `MODE.MULT` results in error, when all numbers occurs only once, this case it picks the biggest one (smallest one would pick 0 (itself))

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: mode.mult was added in Excel 2010, so this solution won't work on older versions (the OP doesn't indicate the Excel version).  It's an array function.  Is this one of those cases where you can use it inside another function without needing to enter the formula as an array formula?